# MS SQL SERVER 2016 Constant CPU usage of 10% ALL DB Offline

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

MS SQL Server 2016 takes 10% constant CPU usage, the usage is even if I take all the databases offline. This was never the behavior of MS SQL Server in past.CPU fan starts running in high speed. If there is no operation in background why take so much CPU. 10% of a Core I7 is too much at idle.

Machine Spec.
Windows 8.1, 6GB RAM, Core i7 2nd Gen 2.2Ghz

Diagnosed the problem see solution.

Comment: Ok .. so what is your concern .. should it be taking 50% or 80% CPU ? What kind of activity is going on on the server ?

Comment: No activity but CPU usage is taking 8% to 10% all the time. This was not a case in SQL SERVER 2008 or 2005.

Comment: If there is no activity, burning CPU is just a waste. Its OK to have less than 10% CPU when there is no activity.

Comment: 10% CPU usage is by the SQL server process in Process Monitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and fixed it. The problem was less physical memory available. I had 90% physical memory usage after freeing up memory usage upto 84% the cpu usage went down to 0%.

Comment: You should have your max memory set away from default .. e.g. 4 or 4.5 GB.